# Why does performance improve by 32-fold when using FP32 instead of FP64 (not 2-fold)?

Tags: graphics-card, performance, 64-bit, gpu

Consider the [NVIDIA Quadro RTX 8000](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/quadro-rtx-8000.c3306) (specs below). Using it to perform single (32-bit precision) gives a theoretical performance of 16.31 TFLOPS. If we reduce the precision to half-precision (16-bit), the theoretical performance *doubles* to 32.62 TFLOPS. However, if we halve the precision from 32-bit to 64-bit, the theoretical performance falls by *32-fold* to 509.8 GFLOPS. **Why is the performance loss from FP32 to FP64 so much greater than the performance gain had from moving from FP32 to FP16?**

[image]

I recognize that this is not always the case for each GPU, but my impression is that for many GPUs, the gains had from going from FP64 -> FP32 are much larger than the gains had from going from FP32 -> FP16.

Comment: graphics almost never use FP64, therefore the FP64 units, if available, are for GPGPU usage, hence will not be as optimized as FP16 and FP32 due to the lack of internal hardware units. Older GPUs don't even have the FP64: [Emulating FP64 with 2 FP32 on a GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29344800/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the default register size within the units is 32-bits.

A 32-bit register can hold two 16-bit values that can be multiplied across resulting in a doubling of performance.

On the other hand multiplying 64-bit values would require either 4 registers (two 64-bit values split into 32-bit parts each) or memory load/stores between doing the lower 32-bit and then the higher 32-bit of the 64-bit value. There would be additional load/stores and bytes needed to handle overflow which might use more registers. Doing 64-bit floating point math in 32-bit registers is workable, but it is far from a simple halving due to being double width.  There is a lot of additional math involved because you can't do a simple "add these two registers together" but instead have to do the math the long way around.

From Stack Overflow [Multiplying 64-bit number by a 32-bit number in 8086 asm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55486908/278545)

> For the final code (with merging); you'd end up with 8 MUL instructions, 3 ADD instructions and about 7 ADC instructions.

The whole point in vector processors is that they work on *streams* of instructions and data and even in a GPU with massive bandwidth memory access is expensive, especially as your data has a dependency on previous parts of the calculation. Out of preference a vector processor just wants a stream of "run this simple code against this huge array" and a lot of repeated runs on one piece of data quickly eats up bandwidth and processor cores.

There is evidence that [FP64 performance](https://wccftech.com/nvidia-gm200-gpu-fp64-performance/) on "gaming" cards is crippled due to having very few or no FP64 capable units. As a result you end up limited to doing 64-bit math "the hard way" in 32-bit registers.